# How can I expose my first web application in Google?

Tags: web, web-applications, release

I release my first `Django` web application.

But can't get search result of my sites even I enter keyword similar with my url(domain)

How can I expose my site in google?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[Submit your URL](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?pli=1) to Google would be my first thought along with considering the question of where are you expecting your site to fall amongst all the other sites that probably aren't referencing it to be ranked that high as Google may well want to see other sites referencing yours to know what to associate with it.